# Unable to access mysql database from asterisk dialplan

Tags: mysql, database, asterisk

I have updated from Asterisk 1.6 to Asterisk 11. I was using MySQL command in asterisk dialplan to access the database on Asterisk 1.6, but now this command seems to be not working. After going through some previous posts, I guess that MySQL command is not supported by Asterisk 11. Can someone please tell me what can be the alternative to MySQL and how can i configure such alternative?

Following is what I'm trying to do in dialplan:

```
exten => _xxxx,n,MYSQL(Connect connid localhost user pswd db)
exten => _xxxx,n(noerror),MYSQL(Query resultid ${connid} SELECT system FROM user_to_system WHERE callerID='${CID}')
exten => _xxxx,n(fetchrow),MYSQL(Fetch foundRow ${resultid} system)
exten => _xxxx,n,MYSQL(Clear ${resultid})
exten => _xxxx,n,MYSQL(Disconnect ${connid})
```

Comment: This syntax is deprecated, try to google: asterisk AGi database

Comment: No, use agi for this care is overkill

Answer (score 3):

Most likly that mean you have no app_mysql and res_mysql compiled.

For new dialplan recommend use res_odbc and func_odbc for database access. It will manage connections for you, just need put sql you want and use like usual dialplan function.

This page describe how to use func_odbc

http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+func+func_odbc

As other option you can use REALTIME function, but it more complex to use. Mysql realtime can be compiled, but not recommended for use becuase of mysql license issues(will be removed in future builds)

Comment: Do I need to download and install any package to use func_odbc?  Also it is tough to comprehend the use of func_odbc from provided link, it would be very helpful if you could let me know an example to read and write in database from dialplan using func_odbc.

Comment: Yes,see info on link above

Comment: The app_mysql resides in the addons/ folder in the source tree. Use the module show like app_mysql.so

Comment: Yes, but it is obsoleted and REALLY can be REMOVED in future. So recomended way now for new dialplan is use ODBC.